# Java : Convert ODF to PDF for prod env without JODConvert

Tags: java, pdf, odt

I need to convert ODT document to PDF in using a Java server, embedded on a Tomcat.

I found some solutions about JOD Converter but it seems not stable for production environment. Moreover, the software could be received many requests from different clients.

Someone have a idea ? Or feedback about JODConverter in a stressful environment ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If in the server you're working with there is any tool (just like OpenOffice or Microsoft Word) which could convert the document, you can always youse [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/).

As the website states

> JACOB is a JAVA-COM Bridge that allows you to call COM Automation components from Java. It uses JNI to make native calls to the COM libraries. JACOB runs on x86 and x64 environments supporting 32 bit and 64 bit JVMs.

You could make a call to the beforehand mentioned converting tool with the params you need to obtain the PDF.